# How to override default `solr.home` in XML files under `Catalina/localhost`?

Tags: debian, tomcat, environment-variables, solr, tomcat7

I'm trying to configure two instances of Solr on the same host and I'd like to override `solr.home` for each instance.

I've created two files under `Catalina/localhost/` as suggested in [Solr Tomcat wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrTomcat#Multiple_Solr_Webapps):

```
$ cat solr-prod.xml 
<Context docBase="webapps/solr-prod.war" debug="0" crossContext="true" >
   <Environment name="solr/home" type="java.lang.String" value="/opt/solr-prod/home" override="true" />
</Context>
$ cat solr-qa.xml 
<Context docBase="webapps/solr-qa.war" debug="0" crossContext="true" >
   <Environment name="solr/home" type="java.lang.String" value="/opt/solr-qa/home" override="true" />
</Context>
```

Btw. I've tried to use absolute path, but without success.

However upon Tomcat restart, it's ignoring my configuration:

```
$ sudo sh -x /etc/init.d/tomcat7 start
...
+ catalina_sh start
+ sed s/\"/\\\"/g
+ echo -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dsolr.solr.home=/opt/solr/home -Dsolr.data.dir=/opt/solr/data -Xmx128m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
+ JAVA_OPTS=-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dsolr.solr.home=/opt/solr/home -Dsolr.data.dir=/opt/solr/data -Xmx128m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
```

by setting its own `-Dsolr.solr.home` and `-Dsolr.solr.home` which I don't know from where it's coming.

The above configuration files are loaded and running according to *Tomcat Web Application Manager* at `/manager/html`.

The problem is when I'm accessing my Solr4 instances via web I can see that Args are set for both of them to:

```
-Dsolr.data.dir=/opt/solr/data
-Dsolr.solr.home=/opt/solr/home
```

So it seems that my environment variable is ignored for some reason and it's overridden by argument.

I don't have `/opt/solr` argument hardcoded anywhere either within `/var/lib/tomcat7`, `/usr/share/tomcat7` or in `WEB-INF/web.xml` (which is commented).

Any ideas how to set-up these environment variables correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found these default settings for `solr.home` and `solr.data` in `/etc/default/tomcat7`.

Other possible locations could be in: `/usr/share/tomcat7/defaults.template` as part of `JAVA_OPTS`.

Removing solr variables from there, it allows to use separate solr instances as per config files defined in `conf/Catalina/localhost`.

So for each instance, separate XML files should be created.

For example:

```
<Context docBase="webapps/solr.war" debug="0" crossContext="true" >
   <Environment name="solr/home" type="java.lang.String" value="/opt/solr/home" override="true" />
</Context>
```

where `value` of `solr/home` is the path to solr, either `/opt/solr/home` or `/var/lib/solr` (whatever path you have or already chosen).